# How to replace objects in the scene based on button click using Three.js?

Tags: three.js

**Removing OLD Objects on the Scene and make Scene available to add New Objects**

I've developed an application which has 3D custom objects added to the Mesh and there upon Mesh is added to scene. I also have a Button on my page, when I clicked it, the already created objects should be removed from mesh which is a children of scene and scene should be ready to add new objects like it was the at the first time. I mean, if possible whole mesh can be removed and new mesh with new set of objects should add to the scene.

```
function xyz() // Button click function
{
  // should remove the objects in the scene if exists and make scene available to add 
  // new objects
  for ex: scene.remove(mesh)....???
  // Also needed to clear the renderer??
   .
   .
   .
   do something
 }
 function init()
 {
   // adds the objects to the scene and instantiate renderer
    mesh = New THREE.Mesh({// some material});
    cube = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1);
    object = new THREE.Mesh(cube,material);
    mesh.add(object);
    scene.add(mesh);
 }
 function animate()
 {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();
 }
 function render()
 {
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm making alot of assumptions about your code based on your snippet you included so maybe try:

```
function xyz() {

    var l = scene.children.length
        ;

    //remove everything
    while (l--) {

        if(scene.children[l] instanceof THREE.Camera) continue; //leave camera in the scene

        scene.remove(scene.children[l]);

    }

    //reinitialise your stuff
    init();

}
```

Comment: I've solved this issue, Please could you help me with Picking, in the following post, I've a question in SO

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791812/three-js-picking-is-working-with-custom-geometry-having-multiple-materials